# Database with categorised cloud (meterology) pictures

Tags: data-request, meteorology

I would like to ask if there is a database of Cloud Pictures
classified by type.

**Example:**

The following Picture would be classified in the category: "Cirrus uncinus".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zhang, Liu, and Zhang (2018)](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1029/2018GL077787) share the data from their paper in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/upuil/CCSN-Database).  From the README:

> The CCSN dataset contains 2543 cloud images. According to the World
>   Meterological Organization’s genera-based classification
>   recommendation, we divide into 11 different categories： Ac, Sc, Ns,
>   Cu, Ci, Cc, Cb, As, Ct, Cs, St. It is worth noting that contrails have
>   consideration in our dataset. Representative sample images from each
>   category are shown below. Ci = cirrus; Cs = cirrostratus; Cc =
>   cirrocumulus; Ac = altocumulus; As = altostratus; Cu = cumulus; Cb =
>   cumulonimbus; Ns = nimbostratus; Sc = stratocumulus; St = stratus; Ct
>   = contrail.

**Citation**

> Zhang, Jinglin, et al. "CloudNet: Ground‐Based Cloud Classification
>   With Deep Convolutional Neural Network." Geophysical Research Letters
>   45.16 (2018): 8665-8672.